# Trouble sorting an array , what changes should I make to plot the chart?

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, sorting, d3.js

I am trying to load csv files to plot a chart. Sort technique has been used to sort the array and plot the chart.

```
 var data = [];
   console.log("here");

 d3.csv("data.csv", function(csvData) {

 csvData.forEach(function (d,i) {
data[i] = {
  first: +d.first, 
  second: +d.second,
  text: d.text
} 
});
 console.log(data);

var tmp = [];
tmp.forEach(function(d) { data.push(d); });

var sortedData = data.sort(function(a,b) { 
return a.text > b.text ; 
});


console.log(data);


var text = [];

d3.csv("text.csv", function(csvData) {

csvData.forEach(function (d,i) {
datam[i] = {
  first: +d.textlist
} 
});
console.log(text);
```

And Here is the link for the complete chart http://plnkr.co/edit/5CeSy2p69TugY3aICc3j?p=preview.

Am I using the right technique to sort data

```
var sortedData = data.sort(function(a,b) { return a.text > b.text ; }); after assigning var tmp = []; ?
```

I want a plot like this

[image]

But I get a plot like this

[image]